# How to combine 2 views and a table into 1 view?

Tags: sql-server

I have the following 2 views:

```
SELECT [Report Year]
      ,[Scenario]
      ,[Country_Style_Code]
      ,[Wholesale Volume]
      ,[Fact Measures]
      ,[Fact Values]
  FROM [dbo].[UnPivoted_Fact_NoVolumeInFactMeasures]
```

and

```
SELECT [Report Year]
      ,[Scenario]
      ,[Country_Style_Code]
      ,[Wholesale Volume]
      ,[Fact Measures]
      ,[Fact Values]
  FROM [dbo].[UnPivoted_Fact_OnlyVolumeInFactMeasures]
```

as well as this table:

```
SELECT [Report Year]
      ,[Scenario]
      ,[Country_Style_Code]
      ,[Accounts]
      ,[Value]
  FROM [dbo].[Fact_AccountsUnpivoted]
```

How do I combine all these into a new view? Currently I have the following view as a union between just the 2 views above, but I would like to add the table as well, but not sure how with the different column names (Accounts, Value)

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[UnPivoted_Fact]
  AS (
    SELECT * FROM [UnPivoted_Fact_NoVolumeInFactMeasures] 
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM [UnPivoted_Fact_OnlyVolumeInFactMeasures]
  );
```

Note: Accounts is equivalent to Fact Measures, and Value is equivalent to Fact Values

Note2: Wholesale Volume exists in "Accounts" in the table. In the 2 views, One View has the Wholesale Volume aliased as "Volume" in the Fact Measures (so Volume is the only value in the Fact Measures)  while the other view doesn't have this alias and includes all other measures/accounts instead.

---

SQL for [UnPivoted_Fact_NoVolumeInFactMeasures] view:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[UnPivoted_Fact_NoVolumeInFactMeasures]
  AS (
      SELECT
      [Report Year]
      ,[Scenario]
      ,[Country_Style_Code]
      ,[Wholesale Volume]
      ,[Fact Measures]
      ,[Fact Values] 
      FROM ( SELECT
      ,[Report Year]
      ,[Scenario]
      ,[Country_Style_Code]
      ,[Wholesale Volume]
      ,[Gross Revenue]
      ,[Equity Income]
      ,[Other Income]
      ,[EBIT] 
      ,[Wholesale Volume] as [Volume]
      FROM [dbo].[Fact] ) AS Fact
      UNPIVOT ( [Fact Values] for [Fact Measures] IN (
           [Gross Revenue]
          ,[Equity Income]
          ,[Other Income]
          ,[EBIT]
          )
      ) AS UnPivoted_Fact
  );
```

sql for [UnPivoted_Fact_OnlyVolumeInFactMeasures] view:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[UnPivoted_Fact_OnlyVolumeInFactMeasures]
  AS (
      SELECT
      [Report Year]
      ,[Scenario]
      ,[Country_Style_Code]
      ,[Wholesale Volume]
      ,[Fact Measures]
      ,[Fact Values] 
      FROM ( SELECT 
      [Report Year]
      ,[Scenario]
      ,[Country_Style_Code]
      ,[Wholesale Volume] = 0
      ,[Wholesale Volume] as [Volume]
      FROM [dbo].[Fact] ) AS Fact
      UNPIVOT ( [Fact Values] for [Fact Measures] IN (
          [Volume]
          )
      ) AS UnPivoted_Fact
  );
```

SQL for Fact_AccountsUnpivoted table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Fact_AccountsUnpivoted](
    [Report Year] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Scenario] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Country_Style_Code] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Accounts] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Value] [real] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could continue doing the same thing if the data types line up correctly. Just make sure you have the same number of columns in all your select statements.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[UnPivoted_Fact] AS 
SELECT
    [Source], [Report Year], [Scenario], [Country_Style_Code], ISNULL([Wholesale Volume], 0) [Wholesale Volume], [Fact Measures], [Fact Values]
FROM (
        SELECT 'NoVolumeInFactMeasures' [Source], [Report Year] ,[Scenario] ,[Country_Style_Code] ,[Wholesale Volume] ,[Fact Measures] ,[Fact Values] FROM [UnPivoted_Fact_NoVolumeInFactMeasures]  
    UNION
        SELECT 'OnlyVolumeInFactMeasures', [Report Year], [Scenario], [Country_Style_Code], [Wholesale Volume], [Fact Measures], [Fact Values] FROM [UnPivoted_Fact_OnlyVolumeInFactMeasures]
    UNION
        SELECT 'AccountsUnpivoted', [Report Year], [Scenario], [Country_Style_Code], (
            SELECT [Value] FROM [dbo].[Fact_AccountsUnpivoted] A2 WHERE A2.[Accounts] = 'Volume' AND A2.[Report Year] = A.[Report Year] AND A2.[Scenario] = A.[Scenario] AND A2.[Country_Style_Code] = A.[Country_Style_Code]
        ), [Accounts], [Value] FROM [Fact_AccountsUnpivoted] A WHERE A.[Accounts] <> 'Volume'
  ) S;
```

Comment: yep so how do i join so that Wholesale Volume is also included?

Comment: Just so I'm clear, are you saying that a record exists in the [Fact_AccountsUnpivoted] Table where the [Accounts] column contains the value for [Wholesale Volume]?

If so, what is the criteria for looking up that row? Or am I understanding it incorrectly?

Comment: yes so in the [Fact_AccountsUnpivoted], Wholsale Volume is a value in "Accounts" column.

Comment: please, can you give us the SQL that generates one of the view?

Comment: As for your last comment, you are taking all data in the query @Jason gives you. The '<Join to get this value?>' can be empty (' '), but still need to exists.

Comment: @Alrik please check my updated post, i included the sql statements :)

Comment: Without knowing what data is in that table, or what columns make each row unique, it would be hard for me to construct a query to extract values from that column. I updated the example to simply alias the same column twice. But without more information, I really can't guess as to what SQL to use.

Comment: `[Report Year]
      ,[Scenario]
      ,[Country_Style_Code]` are the only unique columns (linked to PK)

Comment: Give me a minute :)

Comment: Ok .. maybe 10

I created a sub query to get the value out of the table. Can't be 100% sure that it's correct without looking at the data, but you can replace the string value with something that's more appropriate.

Comment: thanks, am i able to use `select *` in the Union statements so that i dont have to specify the columns? or is it because we now have the 3rd statament to union teh table as well we have to map the columns by explicitly specifying them?

Comment: Yes, the 3rd statement is the reason for it ... You must ensure that the column order is the same among all queries in the union. It might so happen that the column orders in the 2 views match to there will be no issue, but it's best practice to explicitly specify them so there is no confusion.

Comment: I think this is working! one thing, i have some Wholesale Volume fields that are showing as NULL. how do i convert them into 0 instead of NULL? Ive used `COALESCE([Wholesale Volume], 0) [Wholesale Volume]` for the first 2 views in the select but it didnt do anything, i still see some NULLs

Comment: I added an ISNULL to the query outside the UNION statements to catch all instance.

Comment: @Cataster ... Hard to say. I'd have to see it.I will mention that a UNION statement automatically removes duplicates unless you use UNION ALL which will preserve them.

Comment: Wait a minute. What if I dont have these extra columns like source, wat happens?

Comment: That will probably eliminate more duplicates between the three data sources if they exist.

Comment: Gotcha. I'll play around with it, was just checking due to your statement ”Just make sure you have the same number of columns in all your select statements."

Comment: @Jason hey if you dont mind, can you help me out with one extra criteria im working on? There has been a slight change to the `[Fact_AccountsUnpivoted]` table in which the Accounts are now named differently from the Fact Measures in the `[UnPivoted_Fact_NoVolumeInFactMeasures]` and `[UnPivoted_Fact_OnlyVolumeInFactMeasures]` views.

In order to circumvent this issue, i have created another table "Accounts" with its SQL statement as follows: `CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Accounts](
    [Account] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Account Source Name] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Active] [varchar](10) NULL`

Comment: @Jason (comment continued) So now I want to join this table on the UnPivoted_Fact view creation statement in which `[Fact_AccountsUnpivoted]` Accounts matches `[Account Source Name].` How do i do that?

here is some data from the new Accounts table:

`Account  Account Source Name
Variable Profit VARPROFIT
Variable Warehousing Costs VARPWEO
Volume   WS_VOL` so would this be the correct way to do it in your SQL? `...UNION
        INNER JOIN [Accounts] Acc ON [Fact_AccountsUnpivoted].Accounts=Acc.[Account Source Name]
        SET [Fact_AccountsUnpivoted].Accounts=Acc.Account; SELECT ...`